# Shave/Haircuts during the 3 weeks

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, hair, three-weeks, shaving

What are the reasons why a person may be able shave and/or haircut (two biiiits!- sorry, just had to) during the three weeks? Please use sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 122:

During the 3 week you can shave/haircut if:

- You're a Mohel, Sandek or father a
  boy having a Bris
- Until Rosh Chodesh, for somebody whose Shloshim ended on or after 18 Tamuz (KSA 122:14)
- You can trim your mustache if it interferese with your eating (KSA 122:4)

Comment: Danny Schoemann, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for your well-documented answer! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Great answers.  

The 1st can be found in the commentaries to Rema 551:1.  Most permit haircuts until the week of Tisha B'Av since that day is their Yom Tov.  This extends to a Chasan/Kalla during Sheva Brachos.  The Magen Avraham allows haircuts for Shabbos even during the week of T"B.  The Chasam Sofer limits this to where mourning can still be detected (shaving for those who are clean-shaven).

The 2nd is a case of Tokfo Aveilav.  The Dagul Mervava permits even after R"Ch (until week of) if his Shloshim ended then.  Any idea why not 17 Tamuz?

The 3rd is an example of non-simcha cutting.

Answer (score 4):

The Mishna Berura ([OC 551 sk 32](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=48)) rules that one may shave or take a haircut to look nice for Shabbat if one generally does that action at least once a week.

Comment: The Mishnah Berurah says it is asur. He doesn't say that if you do it every week it is mutar, just that we don't do it and therefore it is asur. At best, you could say he doesn't address a case where one usually does it every week (though I think he would say tough luck).

Comment: @wfb He does address it by saying that laundry and hair-cutting have the same rule. That couldn't be clearer. Why would you think to distinguish the two? Why would he say tough luck (especially before Rosh Chodesh)? In the Beiur Halacha he says a) the Yerushalmi the OZ is based on is not our Girsa, b) even their Girsa is a צע"ג as it is unlcear and doesn't fit in context, c) the proposed reason for that doesn't apply, d) we probably don't paskin like it anyway.

Comment: OK, so you pasken le-kula. The Mishnah Berurah doesn't though. And where does he say laundry and hair cutting are the same? He says they are different, and in the Biur Halachah he has some questions about this

Comment: @wfb I feel like we aren't reading the same texts...

Comment: Here's my text, feel free to insert yours: אכן אם אין לו כתונת לשבת יש להקל, וע"י עכו"ם פשיטא דשרי, אבל בתספורת אסור אפילו לכבוד שבת

Comment: @wfb I see. You must be confused because you're not reading the whole thing... Here is the rest of the MB דבלא"ה אין רגילין לספר בכל שבוע [מ"א] ועיין בבה"ל and here is the Beiur Halacha that he referenced עיין במ"ב שכתבנו לענין תספורת דאסור והנה המ"א הביא זה בשם הגהת אשרי והוא הביא זה מאו"ז ועיינתי בא"ז בהלכות ת"ב וז"ל שם ובחמישי מותרין מפני כבוד השבת פי' מותרין לכבס וללבוש בשבת אבל לספר בחמישי אסור כדאמר בירושלמי ובחמישי מותרין מפני כבוד השבת רב הונא בשם

Comment: רב המנונא אמר לתספורת חייש בה פי' שאסור לספר עכ"ל והנה המעיין בירושלמי גופא לפנינו הגירסא לתספורת הושבה ואף לפי גרסתו ג"כ אי אפשר לומר דכונת הירושלמי להחמיר כי לפי הענין מוכח שם להיפך דתספורת מותר בחמישי בשבת וצע"ג. ועיין בחידושי רע"א שהביא גם בשם התוספות דכביסה ותספורת שניהן שוין להקל: See my summary of his arguments above.

Comment: No, obviously I read that, as I referenced it in my comments above. You are the one who is pretending that the Mishnah Berurah says something other than what he says explicitly. This seems rather intellectually dishonest

Comment: @wfb I think I'm accurately reporting his position. You are correct that I don't accurately report half a sentence that you quoted above out of context. Maybe we should think twice about which of those two things is more intellectually dishonest.

Comment: @DoubleAA Assuming your interpretation (from your comments) is accurate, "The MB rules" suggests that he says so explicitly. Perhaps you might want to use "implies" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Two more answers:

If your Safardi, until the week of Tisha b'Av

Clean-shavers who ascribe to R' YD Soloveichik's comparison to the format of yud bais chodesh may shave until Rosh Chodesh.