# Cutting hair when Rosh Hodesh Av is a Friday

Tags: halacha, hair, rosh-chodesh-new-month, nine-days, erev-shabbat

Is it permissible to cut hair on Rosh Hodesh Av when it comes out on a Friday?

Comment: Don't know who deleted my previous comment, but I really wasn't sure. Haircutting is generally a three weeks type of issue, but it's happening during the nine days. So I'm not sure what to tag it. What do others think?

Comment: Hmm Mishna Berura discusses Friday Rosh Chodesh Av to permit warm showers on it (551:89). Of course, he also allows shaving on every Friday of the three weeks ([jud...](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17086/759)) so no big proof.

Comment: this same question (and answer) should apply to nails as well

Comment: @Menachem I imagine nails should be more meikil as some permit cutting them the whole time. Plus they aren't mentioned in the Mishna ie they are purely a minhag, not an extension of a din.

Comment: You could improve this question by adding in information about why you suspect that it may or may not be.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I _could_, but I might draw criticism for comparing apples to oranges, whereas if I leave it like this it gives people with more experience and more Sefarim - and more creativity - the freedom to explore the underlying issues in depth. Those with the wherewithall to come up with a good answer already know why I'm puzzled, and those who are in the dark already are no worse off not knowing why I'm confused by this. But I can put a little more background in if you'd like.

Comment: @SethJ Just explain why you might think to compare Av to Iyar and ask if anyone has commented on it or pointed out other relevant factors. This question right now is pretty lame. It looks like it was written in 2010 by a different user whom I won't name.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Shulchan Aruch HaRav Orach Chaim 260](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/260664/jewish/The-Laws-of-Rosh-Chodesh.htm)

> One should not take a haircut on Rosh Chodesh, even if it comes out on
>   Friday and the haircut will be taken in honor of the Shabbat.

Yechaveh Daas 4:36 says that one may take a haircut on Rosh Chodesh Av, on whichever day of the week it occurs.

Comment: First of all, this is talking about any Rosh Chodesh, not specifically Rosh Chodesh Av. Secondly, the Sh"A HaRav did not rule accordingly, he just said this is a stringency of R' Yehuda HaChassid that some communities follow.

Comment: I see that Rabbi Monsour is also talking about Rosh Chodesh in general. So this doesn't really answer the question, as it has nothing specifically to do with the three weeks/nine days. -1.

Comment: I don't see what you are referring to in that responsum of ROY's. He seems to be discussing if Sefardim can take haircuts during the three weeks when Ashkenazim can't. I see no reference to Rosh Chodesh anything.

Answer (score 0):

Last week, I asked a respected individual learned in Torah in my community when (in July 2012) it would be forbidden to shave and get haircuts. The answer I received was from the 22nd until the 30th. This answer seems to imply that he would permit shaving and haircuts on the upcoming Rosh Hodesh this Friday.

Comment: Is he Sephardi?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Kind of.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Why? Oh, probably because I spelled Chodesh without the letter C.

Comment: Because Sephardim or meikil on many more things than Ashkenazim during the parts of the nine days that do not fall in the same week as Tisha b'Av. I wanted to see from what perspective he was coming.

Comment: He says that some of us are Sepharadim and some of us are Ashkenazim but all of us are Yehudim. He did learn from a Hakham though, but also Mussar Giants and even a Chassidic Master.

Comment: I agree with his first statement but fail to see it relevance here. As for the latter statement, did he tell you which of those teachers taught/influenced him regarding this particular psak?

Comment: He did not tell me which one, sorry. I assume that he did use his own judgment though. When he showed me, he literally whipped out a calendar and showed me the days, which was really cool IMHO.